# recycler view not scrolling inside bottom sheet dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have structure below

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>

inside ViewPager fragment layout

<LinearLayout android:orientation=vertical>
   <RecyclerView android:nestedScrollingEnabled=false />
   <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

But nestedScrollingEnabled doesn't work from xml. But when I execute code below in bottom sheet fragment, it works, I don't know why

```
    try {
        val field = ViewPager2::class.java.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView")
        field.isAccessible = true
        (field[binding.pager] as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        Timber.e(e)
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
```

Comment: What is this <Parent> tag i am seeing it first time, Also why ur getting view IDs manually. Please provide some data is missing in ur question.

Comment: Check this link https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dynamic-viewpager-inside-bottomsheetdialogfragment-d234b00044f3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pager.children.find { it is RecyclerView }?.let {
    (it as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
}
```

this code solved the problem without using reflection

Answer (score 0):

NestedScrollView: Wrap your ViewPager2 inside a NestedScrollView. This will allow the parent NestedScrollView to handle the scrolling, and you can disable nested scrolling on the ViewPager2:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```